# Foreach loop is displaying one one entry

Tags: php, foreach

Let me show my code first:

**Part 1**

```
<?php foreach($entries['items'] as $entry) : ?>
    <audio preload="none" title="<?php echo $entry->title; ?>" data-date="<?php echo date("M d Y",strtotime($entry->pubDate)); ?>">
        <?php if ( $entry->url != "" ) { ?>
            <source src="<?php echo $entry->url; ?>" type="audio/mpeg" />
        <?php } else { ?>
            <source src="<?php echo $entry->guid; ?>" type="audio/mpeg" />
        <?php } ?>

            <!-- <source src="ogg_version.ogg" type="audio/ogg" /> -->
    </audio>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Part 2**

```
<?php
foreach($entries['items'] as $entry) {
    $output = '<audio preload="none" title="'.$entry->title.'" data-date="'.date("M d Y",strtotime($entry->pubDate)).'">';
    if ( $entry->url != "" ) {
    $output .= '<source src="'.$entry->url.'" type="audio/mpeg" />';
    } else { 
    $output .= '<source src="'.$entry->guid.'" type="audio/mpeg" />';
    }
    $output .= '</audio>';

    return $output;
}
```

Part 1 is okay but part 2 is returning only one entry. I cannot recognize the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$output = '<audio preload="none" title="'.$entry->title.'" data-date="'.date("M d Y",strtotime($entry->pubDate)).'">';
```

Should be

```
$output. = '<audio preload="none" title="'.$entry->title.'" data-date="'.date("M d Y",strtotime($entry->pubDate)).'">';
```

And the `return` call should be outside the loop

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
<?php
    foreach($entries['items'] as $entry) {
    $output = '<audio preload="none" title="'.$entry->title.'" data-date="'.date("M d Y",strtotime($entry->pubDate)).'">';
```

to this

```
<?php
$output = "";
foreach($entries['items'] as $entry) {

  $output.= '<audio preload="none" title="'.$entry->title.'" data-date="'.date("M d Y",strtotime($entry->pubDate)).'">';
```

Your foreach loop is assigning new value every time you are looping. You need to initialize the $output variable and then concatenate it.

Answer (score 3):

This is a logical error. `return` instruction quits a loop on a very first iteration.

The bare bones of your code is:

```
foreach ($somethings as $something) {
  // first iteration has begun
  doSomethingWith($something); // done
  return $something; // done, quite the loop
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you have returned your value from the loop. this will not allow the loop to execute for the second time.

Try this code.

```
<?php
$output='';
foreach($entries['items'] as $entry) {
    $output .= '<audio preload="none" title="'.$entry->title.'" data-date="'.date("M d Y",strtotime($entry->pubDate)).'">';
    if ( $entry->url != "" ) {
    $output .= '<source src="'.$entry->url.'" type="audio/mpeg" />';
    } else { 
    $output .= '<source src="'.$entry->guid.'" type="audio/mpeg" />';
    }
    $output .= '</audio>';
}
return $output;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
<?php
$output='';
foreach($entries['items'] as $entry) {
    $output .= '<audio preload="none" title="'.$entry->title.'" data-date="'.date("M d Y",strtotime($entry->pubDate)).'">';
    if ( $entry->url != "" ) {
    $output .= '<source src="'.$entry->url.'" type="audio/mpeg" />';
    } else { 
    $output .= '<source src="'.$entry->guid.'" type="audio/mpeg" />';
    }
    $output .= '</audio>';
}
 return $output;
```